# Problems with libEG.dll after installing neovide

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, neovide

After installing neovide on my Windows 11 Pro machine, several other apps started to fail because they do not find:

```
C:\tools\neovim\nvim-w64\bin\libEG.dll
```

So I uninstalled neovide, restarted my machine, uninstalled some of the failing apps, reinstalled those apps.

I still get this error message: these apps, even after reinstallation, do not find `libEG.dll`.

**Question: where can I find the reference to the folder-file above?**

I looked into the various PATH variables but there is not any.

Comment: Is the file `C:\tools\neovim\nvim-w64\bin\libEG.dll` exist? Is the folder `C:\tools\neovim\nvim-w64\bin\` in the path? What is [Dependency GUI](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) saying when you analyze `libEG.dl`?

Comment: No, it was not in the path. I ended up removing everything and starting from scratch.

Comment: Did it solved your problem?